# Python: Stuck with taxable income formula to calculate the tax

Tags: python

so i need to calculate the tax using the function in python. i really had a hard time understanding function and now we were given a problem to code. so far this is my i tried my best to understand code. ((attached here is the screenshot of the problem))

```
category_code = input("Enter Category Code: ")
no_dependents = int(input("Enter number of dependents: "))
tax_income = float(input("Enter taxable income: "))

single_tax = tax_income - 17850 - (no_dependents)
head_tax = tax_income - 23900 - (no_dependents)
joint_tax = tax_income - 29750 - (no_dependents)
seperated_tax = tax_income - 14875 - (no_dependents)

def tax_sched(tax_income):
    if category_code == "W":
        print ("Tax: ", single_tax * 0.125 )
    elif category_code == "X":
        print("Tax: ", head_tax * 0.125)
    elif category_code == "Y":
        print("Tax: ", joint_tax * 0.125)
    elif category_code == "Z":
        print("Tax: ", seperated_tax * 0.125 )


tax_sched(tax_income)
```

First, im not sure if my formula is even correct:( and i dont know where should i put the elif statements regarding the number of dependents so that i can substract it to the total tax ( i researched that i should subtract the additional exemption but correct me if im wrong) can you guys help me or give me tips plss

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the image, your formula appears a bit incorrect.

First of all, you need to subtract the dependents exemptions from the taxable income:

```
deps = {1:1500, 2:2300, 3:3100}
taxable_income = tax_income - deps[no_dependents]
```

Also, you need to re-do how the taxing is done. According to your image, for Single, you need to tax 12.5% on the first $17,850, plus 10% of the excess.

So to account for that, it should be written as

```
tax = taxable_income * 0.125 if taxable_income <= 17850 else (17850 * .125) + ((taxable_income - 17850) * 0.1)
print(f"Tax: ${tax:,.2f}")
```

Do the same for the other categories, and you should be good!